# Inserting blank rows depending on number of cells (in each column) filled

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small sample example sheet of data, which will be filled with much more data if I can get this process to work.

What I am trying to do is, based upon the number of cells that are filled in each row, insert the same number of blank lines under that same row and copy everything down all columns that are blank. I have attached two screenshots - a before and after of what the start and end look like, as well as the code used for implementing the blank row insert. So far, all it does is add 8 rows consistently, and is using an older version of Excel. I'm trying to translate it into the new VBA format, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Start: [image]

The result I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Code:

```
Sub IfYes()
Dim Col As Variant
Dim Y As Variant
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Col = "AS"
Y = "Y"
StartRow = 1
BlankRows = 1
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet
  For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
      If .Cells(R, Col) = "Yes" Then
            .Cells(R, Col).Offset(1, 0).Resize(8, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Cells(R, StartRow).Offset(1, 0).Resize(8, 1).Value = .Cells(R, 1).Value
            For C = 1 To 8 Step 1
               .Cells(R, Y).Offset(C, 0).Value = .Cells(R, Col).Offset(0, C).Value
            Next C
            .Cells(R, Col) = "Done"
      End If
  Next R
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
```

I also have another bit of code that I've been trying to use to get this to function properly.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Range
Dim StartRow As Range
Dim i As Long

Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Employee Folders\Jason\crystal spreadsheet - start.xls")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("AMZStart")

With ws1
For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow, "B") = "AMZ" Then Rows(lRow).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
Next lRow
LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
StartRow = 1
For i = StartRow To LastRow
If Cells(i, "C") = "" And i > StartRow Then
Cells(i, "C").Formula = "=SUM(C" & StartRow & ":C" & i - 1 & ")"
StartRow = i + 1
End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: so you want into insert *n* rows based on how many cells on a given row have actual data in them? So if a row has 5 cells filled in, insert 5 rows, if 2 have data, insert 2 rows ...?

Comment: Yes, yes, exactly! The only problem is that I can't seem to get the variable to work. Only for the range N - R, which should just be the 
".Range("[ColumnLetter]" & x).Value". I have a different bit of code which I've tried to get to work as well, but to no avail.

Comment: see my answer, I utilized the `CountA` function to cell how cells are filled with data for each row and used that result to insert the number of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that storing the values in variant arrays can help.

```
Sub expand_Entries()
    Dim v As Long, vAMZs As Variant, vVALs As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, c1 As Long, c2 As Long, c As Long, cs As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        c1 = Application.Match("status", .Rows(1), 0)
        c2 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            cs = Application.CountA(.Cells(rw, c1 + 1).Resize(1, c2 - c1))
            If CBool(cs) Then
                vVALs = .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, c1 - 1).Value2
                With .Cells(rw, c1).Resize(1, cs + 1)
                    vAMZs = .Cells.Value2
                    .Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
                End With
                For c = UBound(vAMZs, 2) To LBound(vAMZs, 2) + 1 Step -1
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(1, c1 - 1).EntireRow.Insert
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(1, c1 - 1) = vVALs
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 8) = vAMZs(1, c)
                Next c
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped ! I haven't really been delving into the world of variables since it hasn't been exactly necessary in writing code for my projects, but I suppose now is as good a time as any. This worked perfectly, and was insanely fast - the process clocked in at less than 2 seconds. O_O

Answer (score 1):

You can use a the `CountA` Worksheet Function inside your `IF` block to determine the count of filled cells. Then just replace the `8`'s with the count of each row.

See code:

```
  If .Cells(R, Col) = "Yes" Then

        'get count
        Dim iCells As Integer
        iCells = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A" & R & ":R" & R))

        .Cells(R, Col).Offset(1, 0).Resize(iCells, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        .Cells(R, StartRow).Offset(1, 0).Resize(iCells, 1).Value = .Cells(R, 1).Value

        For C = 1 To iCells Step 1
           .Cells(R, Y).Offset(C, 0).Value = .Cells(R, Col).Offset(0, C).Value
        Next C

        .Cells(R, Col) = "Done"

  End If
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the assist! :) This definitely helped and I'll have to remember this syntax for later spreadsheets. It looks like an Excel refresher course for me is in order.